# Empty Subscription for RxJs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there an empty `Subscription` in RxJs?
In RxJava, there is [Subscriptions.empty()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subscriptions/Subscriptions.html#empty()).

An empty `Subscription` is a `Subscription` to which unsubscribe does nothing except to change isUnsubscribed to true.

I am looking for it, but I can't find.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes such a thing exists:

RxJS 5 has [`Subscription.EMPTY`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/b5aa15a7f58377310438aa5957e1516749d36219/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L21)

RxJS 4 has [`Disposable.empty`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/disposables/disposable.js#L28)

Comment: Thanks! Subscription.EMPTY is what i want. But Disposable.empty is not. It is not Subscription.

Comment: The nomenclature changed between versions 4 and 5. Subscription s used to be called Disposable s

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but I can think about two things :

- [`Rx.Observable.empty()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/empty.md). That returns an observable which immediately emits an `onCompleted` message.
- [`Rx.Observable.never()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/never.md). That returns an observable which never emits anything.

So both are empty in the sense that they do not emit any `onNext` message. However their completion semantics differ. Does that cover your use case?

Comment: Thanks! but this is not what i want.