# How to initialize a Subscription object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using Subscription to get a parameter from the route in angular. Here is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';


@Component({
    selector: 'farm-house',
    templateUrl: './house.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./house.component.scss']
})
export class GreenhouseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
    private routeSub: Subscription;
    id: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.id = "";
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the compiler says:

> Property 'routeSub' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

My question is, what is the best way to initialize a Subscription object?

Comment: put your `ngOnInit` code in to `constructor`

Comment: @RaviAshara Yeah thanks! this fixes the error but the thing is I'm new to angular so I'm not sure if it's totally ok to do that because in all other examples they subscribed in `ngOnInit`.

Comment: `private routeSub: Subscription=null;`

Comment: @Eliseo I've already tried it, but `null` is not assignable to `Subscription`.

Comment: private routeSub?: Subscription;

it is implicitly undefined...   no problem.

 ngOnDestroy() {
        this.routeSub?.unsubscribe();
    }

note the question mark it stops processing if undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come up with another solution which is using `Subscription.EMPTY` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772729/empty-subscription-for-rxjs).

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';


@Component({
    selector: 'farm-house',
    templateUrl: './house.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./house.component.scss']
})
export class GreenhouseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
    private routeSub: Subscription;
    id: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.routeSub = Subscription.EMPTY;
        this.id = "";
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if(this.routeSub) {
            this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Should just be

`private routeSub: Subscription = new Subscription`

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the cases it's should be enough to check the subscription before unsubscribe.

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
     if(this.routeSub) {
       this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
     }
 }
```

In your case, it's not required to initialize subscription because you already called subscribe method in `ngOnInit()`. Error might come because you are calling `unsubscribe()` directly on *Subscription* without checking it's initialized or not.

Comment: Even that checking is not convincing the compiler! There should be a value to initialize it with.

Comment: @eta32carinae You are already assigned value to it in ngOnInit right, but it’s okay to initialise value as ‘null’ while you declaring it.

Comment: I've already tried that but it says `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Subscription'.ts(2322)`. It seems that moving the `ngOnInit` code to the constructor is the way to go. Thank you by the way.

Comment: you need 'private routeSub?: Subscription;'   note the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

Where I have a single subscription.

```
private routeSub?: Subscription;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
    }

    
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
       // no need to do a separate if, use ? it is more readable
        this.routeSub?.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Way 2 where I have multiple subscriptions,  I clean them all up with a single clean up:

```
    private destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>();

Somewhere() {
combineLatest([userService.spaceName$, userService.userName$])
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(([space, username]) => {do something...}
    }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
```

third way - mostly the best way

```
myObservable$: Observable<myInterface>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.myObservable$ = this.myservice.someObservable$;
}

...    html ...
<ng-container *ngIf='myObservable$ | async as list; else simpleInput'>
```

This last process works with onPush and you never forget to unsubscribe.

Note the first way is really handy when you subscribe and unsubscribe as part of the call, even combined with the second way:

```
pollUser(): void {
    // if it has been hear before unsubcribe, otherwise skip it.
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();

    this.subscription= this.someservice(serviceParameters)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(result => {
            this.useResult = result;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use:

```
private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription()
```

During your code, you can then use:

```
this.subscriptions.add()
```

And don't forget to unsubscribe:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you declare  `routeSub: any;` the compiler shouldn't complain.
source: saw it done in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897506/how-to-initialize-a-subscription-object) and i worked for me

Comment: My compiler shows a warning for defining types as `any`. You can see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70132983/3515141) if you're interested.

Answer (score -1):

Unsubscribe is not needed here because Angular destroys this particular subscription for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3003  -- this discusses that it is not required however it is good practice.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you can remove this error by adding `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` in you `tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
   }
}
```

Then you don't need to do this proper initialization, or add a second type `undefined`: `private routeSub: Subscription | undefined`